# Changing the namespace with xslt 1

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having kind of more trouble with this than I should and have not been able to find a solution that seems to be right:

I want to simply change the namespace of an XML document using xslt 1.0 - used withing a java application, using javax.xml.transform.

This is my xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns="http://namespace1.org" type="Document" version="V2_2">
    <Content>
        <Text>asdf</Text>
    </Content>
</Root>
```

This is how it should look after transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns="http://namespace2.org" type="Document" version="V2_2">
    <Content>
        <Text>asdf</Text>
    </Content>
</Root>
```

This is my xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://namespace2.org">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://namespace2.org">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the actual output I get after the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://namespace2.org">2012-11-02T15:39:46.05+01:00DocumentV2_2<ns1:Content xmlns:ns1="http://namespace2.org">
  <ns2:Text xmlns:ns2="http://namespace2.org">asdf</ns2:Text>
 </ns1:Content>
</ns0:Root>
```

There are way to many prefixes added, which I do not want.

I have been able to get rid of the ns+increment prefix by using the following xlst:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://namespace2.org"
 xmlns:cmp="http://namespace2.org"
 exclude-result-prefixes="cmp">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="cmp:{name()}" namespace="http://namespace2.org">
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cmp:Root xmlns:cmp="http://namespace2.org" type="Document" version="V2_2">
 <cmp:Content>
  <cmp:Text>asdf</cmp:Text>
 </cmp:Content>
</cmp:Root>
```

But I have not been able to get rid of the 'cmp' prefix.

Any ideas how I could achieve the desired output?

Comment: I'm curious - if you're using Java, then why on earth are you still using XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

**This generic transformation** (applicable on any XML document, and the new namespace is passed as global/external parameter):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNewNS" select="'http://namespace2.org'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$pNewNS}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name() = '')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri()=namespace-uri(/*)]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{$pNewNS}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root xmlns="http://namespace1.org" type="Document" version="V2_2">
    <Content>
        <Text>asdf</Text>
    </Content>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Root xmlns="http://namespace2.org" type="Document" version="V2_2">
   <Content>
      <Text>asdf</Text>
   </Content>
</Root>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I could not verify this. This is my ouput with your xslt: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="namespace2.org"; ns0:type="Document" ns0:version="V2_2"> <ns1:Content xmlns:ns1="namespace2.org">; <ns2:Text xmlns:ns2="namespace2.org">asdf</ns2:Text>; </ns1:Content> </ns0:Root> Probably this is an issue with the java implementation of the xslt transformer?

Comment: @codeySmurf, The W3C XSLT 1.0 specification doesn't prevent the XSLT processor from adding a generated namespace prefix to the element name. And some XSLT processors, like the one you are using add a prefix to the element names and don't generate a default namespace. The document you get as result and the document I get are exactly the same documents -- they only have differences in their lexical representation. I used Saxon 6.5.4 and got the result that I copied and pasted in my answer. I get exactly the same result with all 12 XSLT processors I have installed on my computer.

Comment: @codeySmurf I get exactly the same result with all 12 XSLT processors I have installed on my computer MSXML 3/4/6, .Net XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform, Saxon 6.5.4, 9.1.07, 9.4.06, .NET, Altova (XML-SPY XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0), XQSharp.