# Need help in XSLT code to change namespace

Tags: xslt

Requesting you to help me with the XSLT Mapping code to convert the below source structure namespace  with the target structure namespace format

Source Structure Namespace :

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<PurchaseOrderDocument creationDate=”2017-09-26T18:37:48.837Z” xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xmlns:soapenv=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/” xmlns:dssuid=”urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1″ xmlns:dsscore=”urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1″>
    <PurchaseQuery>
        <EventDate>20170926</EventDate>
        <bizLocation>
            <id>urn:ddd:id:sgln:0315563.00000.0</id>
        </bizLocation>
        <Serialization>
            <BATCH_ID>3091145AB</BATCH_ID>
            <EXPIRATION_DATE>20190504</EXPIRATION_DATE>
            <PRODUCTION_DATE>20170505</PRODUCTION_DATE>
            <GTIN>04028691544401</GTIN>
            <Count>8088</Count>
        </Serialization>
    </PurchaseQuery>
</PurchaseOrderDocument>
```

Expected Target structure Namespace is

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<ns0:PurchaseOrderDocument creationDate=”2017-09-26T18:37:48.837Z” xmlns:ns0=”urn:global:mns:PurchaseOrder”>
    <PurchaseQuery>
        <EventDate>20170926</EventDate>
        <bizLocation>
            <id>urn:ddd:id:sgln:0315563.00000.0</id>
        </bizLocation>
        <Serialization>
            <BATCH_ID>3091145AB</BATCH_ID>
            <EXPIRATION_DATE>20190504</EXPIRATION_DATE>
            <PRODUCTION_DATE>20170505</PRODUCTION_DATE>
            <GTIN>04028691544401</GTIN>
            <Count>8088</Count>
        </Serialization>
    </PurchaseQuery>
</ns0:PurchaseOrderDocument>
```

Comment: Are you having any specific problem? Or are you basically looking for a XSLT tutorial?

Comment: Check these links first : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431359/xslt-to-change-namespace-prefix) -- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286987/xslt-to-change-namespace-in-element) -- [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974473/changing-the-namespace-with-xslt-1) . They may help you find what you are seeking! there are about "XSLT to change namespace"

Comment: Hi..i have used below xslt ..but this is removing the whole namespace but i also need to add a new namespace at target end which is not happenin with the below code i am using................................................<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>


-<xsl:template match="*|@*">


-<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">

<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: In those links that were provided..i am unable to relate it to my condition. kindly help me

Comment: Hello Team,creationDate=”2017-09-26T18:37:48.837Z” is the value coming from source structure.I am having issue while changing the namespace as i have this creationDate parameter.The XSLT  which i mentioned above is removing all the namespaces , I am facing difficulty  to write code for this line "<ns0:PurchaseOrderDocument creationDate=”2017-09-26T18:37:48.837Z” xmlns:ns0=”urn:global:mns:PurchaseOrder”>
    <PurchaseQuery>" . I am very new to XSLT . Requesting you help me with your suggestions.